# How to center WP7 Bing Map around a number of pushpins

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am using the RTM WP7 Bing Maps control. I have a number of pushpins at lat/long locations. I want to move and zoom the map to show all the pushpins.

With the Silverlight Bing Maps control I could create a bounding box from a number ot lat/longs and tell the  map to zoom using this.

All I can see on the WP7 Bing Maps control is a Center property.

Any ideas how to do this?